# Why does my function not recognize the style of an element correctly?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, display

I have three divs. Only the first one is visible when the page loads.After clicking on a button, the second div becomes visible. After clicking on it again, the third div should also become visible, but it doesn't and I do not understand why.

I am changing the display of the divs via a js "if statement" that checks if a div is already visible, or not.

Am I doing something wrong?

```js
function displayMore() {
  if (document.getElementById("div_02").style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById("div_02").style.display = "block";
  } else if (document.getElementById("div_03").style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById("div_03").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#div_01 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}

#div_02 {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: violet;
}

#div_03 {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_01"></div>
<div id="div_02"></div>
<div id="div_03"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="displayMore();" value="Display More">
```

Comment: You must use `==` not `=` inside `if`

Comment: WRONG `if (document.getElementById("div_02").style.display = "none") {`
CORRECT: `if (document.getElementById("div_02").style.display == "none") {`

Comment: @MTK I just changed my code according to your answers. It still does not work...

Comment: Ok I see it. ONLY inside parentesis you must use ´==´ ... 
`document.getElementById("div_02").style.display == "block";` must be with `=` NOT `==`

Comment: `function displayMore() {
  if (document.getElementById("div_02").style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById("div_02").style.display = "block";
  } else if (document.getElementById("div_03").style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById("pictureDiv_03").style.display = "block";
  }
}` This must work

Comment: I have voted for reopen because OP has updated his question with the hints which was the reason for the duplicate and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MTK Yeah, it still does not work.

Comment: No. but if not other mistakes Must working. If the logical of the function are wrong .. not work

Comment: @Alex I will probably mark your answer as correct, since it solves the problem. I am just trying to understand what is wrong with the way I was doing it.

Comment: He doesn't go inside the condition because `document.getElementById("div_02").style.display` is empty as you can see by log its value before the condition. In your original question you haven't checked == you just set its value with = thats why he revealed the first.

Comment: @Alex I now understand, and found a way to make it work my way (using inline css for display, instead of external css), but your solution works better for the overall project. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a counter variable. The counter represents your current div, when you add a new div then increase your counter.
You can use `nextElementSibling` to set the style of your next element.

```js
let counter = 0;

function displayMore() {
  let currentDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[counter];
  console.log(currentDiv.nextElementSibling.style.display)
  currentDiv.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
  counter++;

}
```

```css
#div_01 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}

#div_02 {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: violet;
}

#div_03 {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_01"></div>
<div id="div_02"></div>
<div id="div_03"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="displayMore();" value="Display More">
```